# armadillo how to get mean of vec3

Tags: c++, armadillo

I need to accumulate lots of 3d data (in arma::vec3) and then I want to compute its mean. How can this be done in a faster way than iterating through every x, y, z data?

For now, I am storing my data as

```
std::vector<arma::vec3> data3d;
```

and then I iterate through the vector to get the mean

```
for (auto &v: data3d) {
  mean_x += v(0); mean_y += v(1); mean_y += v(2);
}
mean_x/=data3d.size();mean_y/=data3d.size();mean_z/=data3d.size();
```

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use

```
arma::mat dataset(data_points, dim);

// populate dataset

arma::rowvec mean_vec = mean (dataset);
```

If there is no specific reason for which you are storing `vec3` objects in CPP STL `vector`.

If you want to grow the matrix at runtime, then you can use the [`resize`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#resize) function. But I would suggest not to grow one row at a time, instad accumulate rows in a buffer, and then grow the main matrix in blocks.

Comment: Thank you. But can this grow dinamically? With the STL vector, I am using `reserve()` and then `puch_back()` every iteration. Are there equivalents?

Comment: You can use `join_rows` function, but it may be not that much a good idea. Instead, you can make data matrix segments for example each having `n` data points, when one is full, then it goes to the second one, and then that one is also full, you can merge both of them into one. Else simple compute the mean of the different matrix objects and take a mean of them. I personally would not iterate over like what your code represents.